# Formato de data incompatível ao importar dados do Excel para MySQL (00-00-0000 VS 0000-00-00)

Tags: java, mysql, microsoft-excel, data

Estou tentando importar os dados de uma planilha do Excel para MySQL, o problema é que tenho uma coluna no Excel que as datas estão no formato `dd-mm-yyyy` e o formato aceito pelo MySQL é o `yyyy-mm-dd`.
Quero saber como converto as datas para `yyyy-mm-dd` antes de importá-la para o MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tanto ir no arquivo excel e alterar o formato da coluna para que a data fique no formato [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), padrão do MySQL, ou mesmo usar uma substring no Java.

Para excel pode usar a opção personalizar e usar esta mascara: aaaa/mm/dd

[image: Excel]

Answer (score 1):

Creio pelo seu dizer na pergunta, que você está importando um arquivo diretamente sem abri-lo correto?

Uma dica para você, seria criar uma trigger no banco de dados antes de inserir (`before insert`) e nela converter o resultado para o esperado pelo banco.

Abaixo segue o link da documentação do MySQL sobre criação de triggers.
[Trigger Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Essa é uma solução, existem outras como abrir o arquivo antes de salvar e através do sistema converter por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Rafael, não entendi direito como você está querendo importar essa planilha para o MySQL, se estiver utilizando a linguagem Java para importá-la poderá usar o método SimpleDateFormat ([java.text.SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) para formatar sua data, ele é bem simples e fácil de ser implementado:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String dateInString = "07/06/2013";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Esse trecho de códico já te atende. Entretanto, se estiver querendo apenas dar uma carga inicial no MySQL pode utilizar uma ferramenta muito útil, o PDI ([Pentaho Data Integration](http://www.pentaho.com/product/data-integration)), sofware muito bom e que particurlamente gosto muito.

Espero ter ajudado!

Abs